# How do you append the fill color (the area) of a series in a bivariate graph in d3?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create multiple series in d3 with different fill colors for the area in between the lines for each series.  I have successfully gotten the first series in, and I am confident I can create multiple series, but I can't figure out how to append the fill color of **just that series.**  I've tried to do something along the lines of: .attr("fill","red"); to append the area but this doesn't work. Here is my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>

    body {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .x.axis path {
    display: none;
    }

    .area {
    fill: steelblue;
    }



  </style>
  <body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <script>

      var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      var parseDate = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S").parse;

      var x = d3.time.scale()
      .range([0, width]);

      var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");

      var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left");

      var line = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

      var area = d3.svg.area()
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .y0(function(d) { return y(d.low); })
      .y1(function(d) { return y(d.high); });

      var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      var context = svg.append("g")
      .attr('class','container')


      d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
      data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
      d.high = +d.positive;
      d.low  = +d.positivelow;
      });

      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
      <!--y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));-->
      <!--y.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.low; }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.high; })]);-->
      y.domain([1720,1780])

      svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area);
      <!--(This line below doesn't work)-->
      <!--.attr("fill","red");-->

      svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Some Y Title");
      });



    </script>
```

Comment: How does it not work? Does it not set the attribute?

Comment: no I get a blank output for the html.  That is the correct syntax?

Comment: Well, the comments you have aren't Javascript comments -- use `//` for those. When you uncomment the `.attr` line, you also need to remove the semicolon at the end of the line before that.

Comment: It displays but it doesn't carry over I still get a blue fill for the graph

Comment: Could you please post the exact code you're running to achieve the fill?